# Set a Ruby class variable, then use it in a class method. HTTParty

Tags: ruby, api, oop, refactoring

I am trying to create an API wrapper for recharge (A Shopify subscription service), I am using the HTTParty gem

```
module RechargeAPI
  require 'httparty'
  BASE_URI = 'https://api.rechargeapps.com'
  API_TOKEN = 'my_token'

  class Client
    include HTTParty
    base_uri BASE_URI
    headers 'X-Recharge-Access-Token': API_TOKEN
  end

  class Customer < Client
    def self.search(params)
      response = get('/customers', query: params)
      self.from_json(response.body)
    end

    def self.find(params)
      self.search(params).first
    end

    def self.all
      response = get('/customers')
      self.from_json(response.body)
    end

    def self.from_json(customers_json)
      customers = JSON.parse(customers_json).dig('customers')
      customers.map do|customer| OpenStruct.new(customer)
      end
    end

  end

end
```

`RechargeAPI::Customer.find(shopify_customer_id: 5363543224286) # returns <OpenStruct accepts_marketing=nil, analytics_data={"utm_params"=>[]}, billing_address1=....`

It works fine, However i feel i am not using the best practices for writing an api wrapper.
Ideally i would set my api token with something like `RechargeAPI.api_token = 'token'` rather than it being hardcoded or in an ENV file. But i dont know how then i would use `headers 'X-Recharge-Access-Token': API_TOKEN`

Also ideally `RechargeAPI::Customer.find(shopify_customer_id: 5363543224863)` would return a `RechargeAPI::Customer` object rather than an `OpenStruct`. I would love to be able to inherit from `Struct` but obviously i cannot as I am inheriting from my `RechargeAPI::Client` class.

Could anybody advise on how i could go about doing this, or any way to improve this code.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally i would set my api token with something like RechargeAPI.api_token = 'token' rather than it being hardcoded or in an ENV file.

The easiest way to do that is to just create accesors on the module:

```
# /lib/recharge_api.rb
module RechargeAPI
  class << self
    attr_accessor :api_token 
  end
end
```

This looks like black magic but remember that modules are an instance of the Module class. This will store the api token in `@api_token` in the module.

For more advanced configuration you can use the [`MyGem.configure` pattern](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/mygem-configure-block).

> Also ideally RechargeAPI::Customer.find(shopify_customer_id: 5363543224863) would return a RechargeAPI::Customer object rather than an OpenStruct. I would love to be able to inherit from Struct but obviously i cannot as I am inheriting from my RechargeAPI::Client class.

There is one big problem with this design which is that your `RechargeAPI::Customer` class will be doing way too much if its responsible for both sending HTTP requests and managing the data from the response.

I get the idea of wanting to build an ActiveRecord like interface but in this case you'll end up with a very hard to deal with god class.

Instead let the clients just do HTTP which is complicated enough once you actually start handling errors and unexpected responses.

```
# /lib/recharge_api/client.rb
require 'httparty'
module RechargeAPI
  # Base client class for RechargeAPI
  class Client
    include HTTParty
    format :json
    headers 'X-Recharge-Access-Token' => RechargeAPI.api_token
    def initialize(**options)
      @options = {
         # set defaults here
      }.merge(options)
    end
  end
end
```

```
# /lib/recharge_api/customer_client.rb
module RechargeAPI
  # Gets customer data from RechargeAPI
  class CustomerClient < Client
    def search(params)
      # @todo what are you going to do when the request is not successful?
      handle_response(self.class.get('/customers', query: params))
    end

    def find(params)
      search(params).first
    end

    def all
      # @todo what are you going to do when the request is not successful?
      response = self.class.get('/customers')
      handle_response(response.body)
    end

    private 

    # refactor into a separate object if this gets too complex
    def handle_response(json)
      # @todo what are you going to do when the JSON does not contain the 
      # expected values?
      json.dig('customers')&.map do |raw| 
        Customer.from_json(raw)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
customers = RechargeAPI::CustomerClient.new(
  foo_option: 'bar'
).all
```

Then create a data object which takes the raw JSON data and normalizes it:

```
# /lib/recharge_api/customer.rb
module RechargeAPI
  # Model representing a customer
  class Customer
    attr_accessor :email
    attr_accessor :name
    attr_accessor :is_karen
    # Simple attribute assignment from keyword arguments
    def initialize(**attributes)
      attributes.each do |key, value|
        send("#{key}=", value)
      end
    end

    # factory method for creating a model from the API response
    # refactor into a separate object if it gets too complex   
    def self.from_json(**json)
      # do your data normalization here
      new(**json)  
    end
  end
end
```

This lets you test it without touching the application boundry and stubbing the API. You could also inherit from OpenStruct if you want to allow any attributes.

Comment: Sometimes you will even want to add a separate object  that sits between your client and "model" and just handles normalizing the data.

Comment: `is_karen` hahaha, Thanks so so much i will take this on board! 
with the `# @todo what are you going to do when the request is not successful?` do you think its worth making a method for each get so i can handle errors?

Comment: Also what does the `format :json` do in `RechargeAPI::Client` ? Thanks again!

Comment: What you can do is create a `RechargeAPI::Client#get` method which wraps the HTTParty get method and consolidates the error handling.

Comment: Thanks! also found this, when you use `format :json` HTTParty will automatically set the content type and handle JSON encoding and decoding

Comment: To find a customer I am doing `customer = RechargeApi::CustomerClient.new.search(shopify_id: person.shopify_id)` This feels wrong because i am instantiating a new class each time i make a query, Is this not wrong? It feels as though my `RechargeAPI::CustomerClient#search, #find and #all` should be class methods so i can do `RechargeAPI::CustomerClient.search(foo: 'bar')` what do you think? Thankyou, really appreciate the help !

Comment: Doesn't the api have an endpoint which leads to a single record - something like `'/customers/:id'`?

Comment: So you get a single record by going to `/customers?shopify_id=foo` but you can also access by `/customers?customer_id=xyz` or  `/customers?address_id=xyz` and a few others. I would like my search method to be able to include any of these as params e.g. `#search(address_id: 'xyz)`

Comment: https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/ruby-keyword-arguments

Comment: It works fine, I was just wondering if it is wrong to be calling  it like `RechargeApi::CustomerClient.new.search(foo: 'bar')` rather than it being a class method? Really appreciate this help. Let me know if you have anywhere where i can show my support for this help!

Comment: Do you think a creating a search class method that calls `self.new.search` is wrong?

Comment: Im a bit stuck now with setting my token, I have moved `RechargeAPI.api_token = 'token'` into `config/initializers/recharge.rb` however, in my controllers and models the token is set to nil